# How to programmatically disable a bluetooth profile for a single device?

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to toggle a bluetooth profile programmatically while keeping the bluetooth device connected? Is there a way to achieve this?

I used this method but it is diconnecting the bluetooth connection which is not what I want to achieve.

```
BluetoothHeadset.class.getDeclaredMethod("disconnect", BluetoothDevice.class);
disconnectHeadset.invoke(HeadsetProxy, device
```

[image: What I would like to achieve]

Comment: I don't think the Bluetooth standard provides for such a function. What do you want to achieve with this function?

Comment: I have a bluetooth device that automatically reconnects when I disconnect it, so I want to disable its headset profile so it is no longer in use and enable it again when I needed it without having to disconnect the connection completely. I am building an application that switches bluetooth devices depending on charging state.

Comment: Android has the [BluetoothProfileManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/bluetooth/BluetoothProfileManager) class which is in principle capable of providing such functionality.  However, I am not sure whether this class would also allow the very specific function you want.